# inserting/emplacing into a hash table where the position is already occupied

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, insert, complexity-theory

So let's say I have something like this:

```
 struct equity{          ///keep in hash table
     long long numSharesTraded;
     list<order> buyList;
     list<order> sellList;       //put in priority queue
};
```

if I want to insert something into either the buyList or sellList, is it necessary that I check and see where in the hash table the particular equity who's list i should be adding to is?... so I eventually end up having something like:

```
 map[i].equity.buyList.push_back(orderI'mPushing);
```

?

or is there another way that I can do so without having to search for it every time? From my understanding, searching for the particular equity is in constant time on average ( O(n) worst case ), but I'd like to get rid of that search if at all possible...

so 1) is there a way to add to the list without searching to see if that equity is already in the hash table every time and 2) if I have to search every time, will that cause the run time to be substantially longer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The unordered associative containers from C++11 (e.g. `std::unordered_set`, there are similar containers in [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/unordered.html) if you can't use C++11) have several `insert()` member functions, in particular

```
std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );
```

inserts an element into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key. This returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element (or to the element that prevented the insertion) and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place. There are also ranged insertion function to insert a collection of items (separated by a `first` and `last` iterator) into your container.

You can use it like this (use `std::unordered_map` if you want to store more stuff along with an order):

```
struct equity { /* like before */ };
std::unordered_set<equity> orders;
auto result = orders.insert(orderI'mPushing);
if (result.second) 
    // handle first-time insert by reusing result.first
else
    // item was already stored
```

The individual insertions have amortized `O(1)` complexity, meaning that inserting a large number of `N` elements has `O(N)` time complexity. So on average, you should not have any penalty from the repeated searches.

However, if you are doing super-high frequency trading and are facing real-time latency constraints on individual insertions, you might elect to use a regular `std::set` which has a slower but more predictable `O(log N)` complexity.